# OpenVPN Start Service

Tags: centos, openvpn, services, hosting-services

I am trying to configure OpenVPN on my CentOS 7 box.

I am following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7#step-1-%E2%80%94-installing-openvpn

I have got up to step 5 to actually start the openvpn@server.service, and it keeps giving me this error after running: systemctl start openvpn@server.service

Job for openvpn@server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status openvpn@server.service for details.

When I run systemctl status openvpn@server.service

There is an error that says failed to start openvpn robust and highly flexible tunneling application on server.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

It was the ta.key file that was not commented out in the server.conf file.